# Laravel stripe and cashier no such payment method

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using Laravel 7 and i am integratng stripe with cashier and i am facing issue

```
No such PaymentMethod: 'tok_1HBxFdEft5GkDC4v7ZnPgW5Y'
```

I am using custom checkout forms Html code is

```
<form class="rt-formtheme rt-paymentmethodform" method="POST" action="{{route('subscripe.process')}}" id="subscribe-form">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="div-stripe-errors col-12" style="margin-top: 30px;"></div>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Choose your card</legend>
                        <!-- <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="rt-btn rt-savebtn">Save</button>
                        </div> -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="rt-radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="visa">
                                <label for="visa"><img src="{{asset('images/visa.png')}}"  alt=""></label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="rt-radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="american-express">
                                <label for="american-express"><img src="{{asset('images/american-express.png')}}"  alt=""></label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Card Number</label>
                            <input type="text" name="cardnumber" class="form-control" placeholder="1234 5678 9012 3456" data-stripe="number">
                        </div>
                        <div class="rt-twocols">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="rt-twoinputfieldholder">
                                    <div class="rt-twoinputfieldbox">
                                        <label>Expiry Month</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="expirymonth" class="form-control" placeholder="MM" data-stripe="exp-month">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="rt-twoinputfieldbox">
                                        <label>Expiry Year</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="expiryyear" class="form-control" placeholder="YY" data-stripe="exp-year">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>CVC</label>
                                <input type="text" name="cvv" class="form-control" placeholder="123" data-stripe="cvc">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group margin-zero rt-savecarddetailbox">
                            <span class="rt-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="savecarddetail" id="savecarddetail">
                                <label for="savecarddetail">Save Card Details</label>
                            </span>
                            <button type="submit" class="rt-btn float-right">Checkout</button>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

and js code is

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script>
Stripe.setPublishableKey('{{ env("STRIPE_KEY") }}');
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#subscribe-form').submit(function(e){
        
        var form = $(this);
        
        form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

        Stripe.card.createToken(form, function(status, response) {
            if (response.error) {
                form.find('.div-stripe-errors').text(response.error.message).addClass('alert alert-danger');
                form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                // append the token to the form
                form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="cc_token">').val(response.id));
                // debugger
                // submit the form
                form.get(0).submit();
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Route is

```
    Route::post('/subscribe_process', 'Dashboard\CheckoutController@subscribeProcess')->name('subscripe.process');
```

and controller method is

```
public function subscribeProcess(Request $request)
{
    try{
        $cc_token = $request->cc_token;
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->newSubscription('Main','Monthly')->create($cc_token);
        alert()->success('User Updated Successfully', 'Success');
        return \redirect()->back();
    }catch(\Exception $ex){
        return $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

and i also create plan on stripe dashboard
[image]

when i create a subscription it show error No such payment method i am new in stripe kindly help me

Answer (score 2):

"No such..." errors are usually caused by either a mismatch in API keys (e.g. using a mixture of your test plus live keys) or by trying to access objects that exist on a different account (e.g. trying to perform an operation from your platform account on an object that was created on a connected account).

Comment: Yes, but somewhere you either have a mismatch in API keys (e.g. using your live key on the client but your test key on the server) or you made the token on one Stripe account and are attempting to use it on a completely different Stripe account, which won't work.

Comment: Thanks alot for your response . It was my mistake i was using old version of apis now i fixed it using new method. First i send payment intent and then create payment method and i solved this issue . i used this https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/billing documentation